# noUiSlider: Set a background color for the limited area

Tags: nouislider

I'm using noUiSlider with the "soft limits" (https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-soft-limits) and I want to set a specific background color for the area that's limited. For example, if I can't drag the handle anywhere across the first 20 values, this section of the bar should have a red background color.

This is because I need three different background colors:

1 For the limited area

2 For the area on the left side of the handle

3 For the area on the right side of the handle

[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiEzD.jpg)
Hope you understand what I mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in CSS, using `linear-gradient`:

```
.noUi-background {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a2ea4c 20%, #07aa91 20%, #07aa91 80%, #a2ea4c 80%);
}
```

[image: slider limit colored areas]

Add a `padding` and more color stops for any number of colored areas.