# noUiSlider: how to style padding?

Tags: javascript, css, nouislider

How to set background-color for noUiSlider padding?

(default, linear, one handle) like this:

[image]

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561800/nouislider-set-a-background-color-for-the-limited-area), but:

1) I have no `.noUi-background` class (version 14.0.3).

2) I want to change slider padding with `updateOptions`. So I need automatic style change.

Answer (score 0):

I think this worked for me.

The snippet can't work here but I think you can add the `.noUi-background` class to your slider then update the gradient style when calling the update function on the slider.

```js
var updateSlider = document.getElementById('slider-update');
var updateSliderValue = document.getElementById('slider-update-value');

/* Set up min and max */
var min = 0;
var max = 40;

/* Create slider */
noUiSlider.create(updateSlider, {
  range: {
    'min': min,
    'max': max
    },
    padding: 6,
    start: 20,
    margin: 2,
    step: 2
});

/* When update the slider, update the gradient style */
updateSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function (values, handle) {
  updateSliderValue.innerHTML = values[handle];
  
  // Update gradient
  let distanceFromMin = (values[handle] - min);
  let sliderRange =  (max - min);
  let valueGradient = 100 * ( distanceFromMin / sliderRange );
  updateSlider.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to right, #a2ea4c "+valueGradient+"%, #07aa91 "+valueGradient+"%)";
});

/* Update min/max when calling updateOptions */
var button1 = document.getElementById('update-1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('update-2');
button1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    min = 20;
    max = 50;
    updateSlider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
        range: {
            'min': min,
            'max': max
        }
    });
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    min = 10;
    max = 40;
    updateSlider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
        range: {
            'min': min,
            'max': max
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/* Class for the gradient */
.noUi-background {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a2ea4c 50%, #07aa91 50%);
}
                
button{
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="slider-update" class="noUi-background"></div> <!-- Adding noUi-background class -->
  <span id="slider-update-value"></span>
  
  <button class="update-button" id="update-1">
  Set range [20, 50]
  </button>
  <button class="update-button" id="update-2">
  Set range [10, 40]
  </button>
</div>
```